# RoR no route matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, methods

I have this code in my routes:

```
   controller :active_car do
    put 'switch_car' => :update
    get 'switch_car' => :edit
   end
```

This is my code in on my edit page.

```
    <% form_tag('switch_car', :method => :put) do%>
<div class="field">
    <label for="car_info_id">Car Name:</label>
    <%= select("", "car_info_id", @available_cars.collect {|v| [v.name, v.id]})%>
</div>
<div>
    <%= submit_tag "Switch Car" %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

When I click submit I get the following routing error.

No route matches "/switch_car" with the url pointing to http://localhost:3000/switch_car?method=put

The get is working just fine as I end the url with switch_car I get my page to edit.  For some reason the put definition is not working.

After changing method to second argument it just doesn't work.  It seems to have post as the method still instead of put.  Here is generated HTML

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="switch_car" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="_method" type="hidden" value="put" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

:method belongs to the "options" hash, which is form_tag's second argument, not the first.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag

Please inspect the html generated by that tag and post it here.

Comment: I no longer get the route error but it still seems to have post as the action.

Comment: I now see the hidden put as stated in the documentation.  Thanks.